# Free venues database which is up-to-date and accurate and allows querying against wide regions?

Tags: foursquare, gis, google-places

Is there a free database for venues (such as cinemas, restaurants, cafes, schools, etc.) which have attributes for the venues such as geographic coordinates, name, contact info, address, type or category, etc.

I know that there are alternatives like [Foursquare Venues Platform](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues). But Foursquare Venues Platform have limits on the number of results per request and square measure of the bounding box.

I need to get a collection of venues on a large area.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) (www.geonames.org)

It is not a perfect fit for what you are asking, but they do have a downloadable (free or paid) database of locations.
You can import it and then get as much data as you want.

It contains a lot of data, but we found that there is a lot of work to be done cleaning it up (we were using the free version)

Maybe the paid will have less noise.

**Do note**, that it will not be as complete as what Foursquare or Google places or Facebook has to offer, but if you need to query a large area with many results, it might fit your needs.

They also have an API (Web Services).